# Unzip specific directory without creating top directory

Tags: command-line, unzip

I have a ZIP file in which there is a top directory where all the files are stored:

```
Release/
Release/file
Release/subdirectory/file
Release/subdirectory/file2
Release/subdirectory/file3
```

I want to extract everything under `Release`, preserving the directory structure, but when I run this:

`unzip archive.zip Release/* -d /tmp`

It creates the top `Release` folder:

```
/tmp/Release/
/tmp/Release/file
/tmp/Release/subdirectory/file
/tmp/Release/subdirectory/file2
/tmp/Release/subdirectory/file3
```

How I can extract everything inside `Release` **without** creating a `Release` folder, like this:

```
/tmp/
/tmp/file
/tmp/subdirectory/file
/tmp/subdirectory/file2
/tmp/subdirectory/file3
```

Comment: Try this `unzip archive.zip  && mv Release/* .`

Comment: @George this still creates a `Release` folder

Answer (score 11):

Create a symlink at the location that the top directory would be extracted to that points at your current location:

```
ln -s . Release && unzip <YourArchive>.zip
```

Then remove the link:

```
rm Release
```

Comment: The order of parameters for `ln` is swapped. It should be `ln -s . Release`.

Answer (score 3):

The `j` flag should prevent folder creation `unzip -j archive.zip -d .`

From the [man page](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html):

```
-j 

junk paths. The archive's directory structure is not recreated; 
all files are deposited in the extraction directory (by default, the
current one).
```

Comment: I think this is close, but the OP was looking to only skip creation of the top level directory and preserve the remaining directory structure.  the `-j` option dumps all files into the current directory without regard to the directory structure in the archive.

Answer (score 1):

#### Python script for flattening extracted tree

The script written bellow extracts zip file and moves files contained within topmost directory out of it to the current working directory. This quick script is tailored to suit this particular question where there is one single topmost directory that contains all the files, although with a few edits can be made suitable for more general cases.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import os
from zipfile import PyZipFile
for zip_file in sys.argv[1:]:
    pzf = PyZipFile(zip_file)
    namelist=pzf.namelist()
    top_dir = namelist[0]
    pzf.extractall(members=namelist[1:])
    for item in namelist[1:]:
        rename_args = [item,os.path.basename(item)]
        print(rename_args)
        os.rename(*rename_args)
    os.rmdir(top_dir)
```

#### Test run

Here's an example of how the script is supposed to work. Everything extracted to current working directory, but source file can be in differet directory altogether. The test is performed on the zip archive of my personal github repository.

```
$ ls                                                                                   
flatten_zip.py*  master.zip
$ ./flatten_zip.py master.zip                                                          
['utc-time-indicator-master/.gitignore', '.gitignore']
['utc-time-indicator-master/LICENSE', 'LICENSE']
['utc-time-indicator-master/utc-time-indicator', 'utc-time-indicator']
['utc-time-indicator-master/utc_indicator.png', 'utc_indicator.png']
$ ls
flatten_zip.py*  LICENSE  master.zip  utc_indicator.png  utc-time-indicator
```

Test with source file being in different location

```
$ mkdir test_unzip
$ cd test_unzip
$ ../flatten_zip.py  ../master.zip                                                     
['utc-time-indicator-master/.gitignore', '.gitignore']
['utc-time-indicator-master/LICENSE', 'LICENSE']
['utc-time-indicator-master/utc-time-indicator', 'utc-time-indicator']
['utc-time-indicator-master/utc_indicator.png', 'utc_indicator.png']
$ ls
LICENSE  utc_indicator.png  utc-time-indicator
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I faced with the same issue. For me the following really simple solution was working fine in bash:

```
$ cd abc 
$ unzip abc.zip -d ../
```

> **[-d exdir]**
>
> An optional directory to which to extract files. By
> default, all files and subdirectories are recreated in the current
> directory; the -d option allows extraction in an arbitrary directory
> (always assuming one has permission to write to the directory). This
> option need not appear at the end of the command line; it is also
> accepted before the zipfile specification (with the normal options),
> immediately after the zipfile specification, or between the file(s)
> and the -x option. The option and directory may be concatenated
> without any white space between them, but note that this may cause
> normal shell behavior to be suppressed. In particular, ''-d ~''
> (tilde) is expanded by Unix C shells into the name of the user's home
> directory, but ''-d~'' is treated as a literal subdirectory ''~'' of
> the current directory.

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip