# Unzip directory only up to a certain point

Tags: zip

Having looked at a few answer, for instance this one: [Unzip specific directory without creating top directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892099/unzip-specific-directory-without-creating-top-directory)

It's not what I'm looking for.

The situation is a zip with the following directories:

/a/b/c/d/e1/...
/a/b/c/d/e2/...

So under d, you have e1 and e2.

What I want to achieve is extracting only those 2, without replicating the entire directory structure, but also without using `-j`, which ignores all paths.

I want the directory structure to exist from `d/` onward.

To be as clear as possible, the extracted folder should look like:

```
d
| - e1
|   |
|   | - fileA
|   | - fileB
| - e2
|   |
|   | - fileC
|   | - fileD
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Same question on superuser with good answers: https://superuser.com/questions/518347/equivalent-to-tars-strip-components-1-in-unzip